# How to handle raw jpeg data

Tags: delphi, jpeg

I have JPG data retrieved by web-request. Also, in "buf" there are same bytes as in JPG file. I want to load this data in TStream or even better in TBitmap.

```
// here are JPG data from http request in string property "UnparsedParams"
buf:=PChar(ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams); 
stream:=TMemoryStream.Create;

// now I will save it into local file
stream.Write(Buf^, length(ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams));
stream.SaveToFile(sFile);
stream.Free;

// and now I will load jpg-image from file 
img.imageName:=sFile;
img.Picture.SaveToFile(sFile);

// and now once again will load in dll's procedure to work something with picture
mydll.ReadFromFile(sFile,0);
// ...and I want to use method "ReadFromMemFile" that handle in-memory data
mydll.ReadFromMemFile(<OleVariant>, <Size>, <zero>);
// ...or maybe better method ReadFromBitmap that handle with Bitmap's handle
mydll.ReadFromBitmap(<bitmap handle> <zero>);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Transfer the data to a stream:

```
var
  ms: TMemoryStream;
....
ms := TMemoryStream.Create;
ms.Write(Buf^, length(ARequestInfo.UnparsedParams));
```

And then load that stream into your image:

```
ms.Position := 0;
jpeg := TJpegImage.Create;
jpeg.LoadFromStream(ms);
img.Picture.Assign(jpeg);
```

If you want to transfer to a bitmap do it like this:

```
var
  bmp: TBitmap;
....
bmp := TBitmap.Create;
bmp.Assign(jpeg);
```

For all any of this to work you must include the `jpeg` unit in your `uses` clause.

I'm not sure about the relevance or otherwise of the final part of your question, the part about your DLL.

FWIW, if ever you wish to save to a file, there's no need for an intermediate memory stream. Create a `TFileStream` and write directly to it.

Comment: @David Heffernan: from some reason there is error when loading stream into TJpegImage object. Error #53. And I want to avoid file-system in hope to save a time, and eventual failure by read/write.

Comment: Error 53 means you have a JPEG file that the `jpeg` code cannot handle. You may need to find a different library. I'm sure if you do a websearch on the error message you'll find lots of help on that. If your question is about error 53, why did you wait until now to mention it.

Comment: I found all of previous errors...Just need to get somehow Bitmap's handle...Now is  img.Picture.Bitmap.Handle = 0. What to do?

Comment: Your picture holds a jpeg image not a windows bitmap. Transfer to a TBitmap as per my answer and read its handle. Why are you using TImage for what seems to be non visual code.

Comment: This is because of that I have one Server app that retrieve an image, show it and handle whatever. Just for visual presentation.... And other app is the same but run as service. This other don't contains any wisual controls of course... Howerver, thank you for your help.